# Travis-CI: "sudo apt-get build-dep" equivalent for container-based infrastructure

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a way to install only build dependencies of a package with the container-based builds of travis-ci?

[The migration guide does not mention build-dep.](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/?utm_source=legacy-notice&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=legacy-upgrade)

It is possible to explicitly list all the dependencies, but an automated method would be favorable.